# Android In-App Billing - queryInventoryAsync returns 0 result

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

i'm experiencing a frustrating issue with in-app billing process.
I've created a new application in dev console, added an inapp product named "P1", which is currently active; I've uploaded my app to the store in alpha version, then promoted to beta, added a tester account and installed the apk on a device (tablet) signed with the tester account and another with dev account.

Now, i'd like to query the store to get informations like price of not owned skus.
Here's my code from my **activity**:

```
private void istantiate() {
     List<String> tmp = new List<String>();
     tmp.add("P1");
     final List<String> skus = tmp;
     mHelper = new IabHelper(mContext, base64EncodedPublicKey);
     // enable debug logging (for a production application, you should set this to false).
     mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);
     //create listener
     bListener = new BillingListener(mHelper, mContext);

     // Start setup. This is asynchronous and the specified listener will be called once setup completes.
     mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
         public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {

             if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                 // There was a problem.
                 return;
             }             
             getInventory(skus);
         }
     });         
}

...

private void getInventory(List<String> skuList) {
    // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
    if (mHelper == null) return;

    // IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skuList, bListener.mQueryFinishedListener);
}
```

Then when query is completed, this piece of code is called:

```
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
   public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

      if (result.isFailure()) {
         // handle error
         return;
       }
      ...

   }
};
```

But returned inventory is empty. Here's **logcat**:

```
     12-13 11:21:36.977: D/IabHelper(6034): Billing service connected.
     12-13 11:21:36.977: D/IabHelper(6034): Checking for in-app billing 3 support.
     12-13 11:21:36.987: D/IabHelper(6034): In-app billing version 3 supported for ***
     12-13 11:21:36.987: D/IabHelper(6034): Subscriptions AVAILABLE.
     12-13 11:21:36.987: D/IabHelper(6034): Starting async operation: refresh inventory
     12-13 11:21:36.987: D/IabHelper(6034): Querying owned items, item type: inapp
     12-13 11:21:36.987: D/IabHelper(6034): Package name: ***
     12-13 11:21:36.987: D/IabHelper(6034): Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
     12-13 11:21:36.997: D/IabHelper(6034): Owned items response: 0
     12-13 11:21:36.997: D/IabHelper(6034): Continuation token: null
     12-13 11:21:36.997: D/IabHelper(6034): Querying SKU details.
     12-13 11:21:37.097: D/IabHelper(6034): Querying owned items, item type: subs
     12-13 11:21:37.097: D/IabHelper(6034): Package name: ***
     12-13 11:21:37.097: D/IabHelper(6034): Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
     12-13 11:21:37.097: D/IabHelper(6034): Owned items response: 0
     12-13 11:21:37.097: D/IabHelper(6034): Continuation token: null
     12-13 11:21:37.097: D/IabHelper(6034): Querying SKU details.
     12-13 11:21:37.097: D/IabHelper(6034): Ending async operation: refresh inventory
```

It's about a week since my inapp product was published, so it isn't a matter of time.
I've tried to clear app data, and restart the device.

**Edit**: Everything works fine using android.test.purchased as test sku.
**Edit 2**: SKUs are "unmanaged"

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution? I'm facing the exact same problem.

Comment: i'm also experiencing this... any results?

Comment: Currently i'm still experiencing the problem

Comment: Man, this is frustrating. Been encountering the same issue, for weeks now. Sometimes it works in Debug mode, but not when downloading from the play store. I'm pretty much clueless as to what's happening. Any chance you figured this out?

Answer (score 6):

I also got this problem but it was fixed once I cleared app data for *Google Play* application. Using adb:

```
adb shell pm clear com.android.vending
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is happening because of caching in Google Play App. Usually, Google Play app cache refreshes once every 24 hours.

@poqueque's solution works if you want to clear cache through command line. You can also goto App settings on the phone and clear data/cache of Google Play app. Make sure to log back into your Google Play account after you do this.

Does anyone know a solution to force refresh Google Play cache through code or query purchases without using cache to get up to date info?

Answer (score 0):

"Owned items response" reports the response code, which in this case is BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK with a value of 0.

Looking at IabHelper.queryPurchases code and IabHelper.getSkuDetails, I suggest a good place to start is getting the data with 'inventory.hasDetails("P1")' or 'inventory.getSkuDetails("P1")' in onQueryInventoryFinished.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but inventory is empty after first call. Those functions return false and null. But with android.test.purchased it works fine :/

Comment: Not sure.  Maybe the SKU doesn't match.  Ensure "P1" is the sku, not just the title (shown in the console after the name - entered as Product ID when you create item).  Maybe it needs to be lower case to be recognized (so you may need to create another item for testing).   Also, have you done any testing with unmanaged skus?

Comment: P1 is the sku, the letter case doesn't affect the results (i've tried with different names). Added other skus but nothing changes.